# How to push a schema object into the array property of another schema object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm-js

### Description

I went through the [realm-js](/questions/tagged/realm-js)  [documentation](https://realm.netlify.com/docs/javascript/2.8.0/#writes) and was unable to find any examples explaining how to push an object into the array property of its parent.

To be a little more clear, I have a Schema `Test` which has a property `data: {type: "data[]", default: []}`, however I am unable to push any `data` objects to it.

### Error:

Here is the error I get.

> Property must be of type 'data', got ([object RealmObject])

### What I tried:

This is what I tried:

```
this.realm.write(()=>{
  const dataObj = this.realm.create('data', data);
  this.user.test.data.push(dataObj);
})
```

What am I doing wrong?

*I also tried to directly push the data directly, but I get a similar error.*

### Test Schema:

```
class Test{
}

Test.schema = {
    name: "test",
    primaryKey: "id",
    properties: {
        id: "string",
        start: "date?",
        duration: "int", //in seconds
        capsule_id: "string",
        creation: "date",
        status: "int",
        height: "float",
        weight: "float",
        time_of_evolution: "string",
        treatment: "bool",
        data: {type: "data[]", default: []},
        symptoms: {type: "symptom[]", default: []},
        meals: {type: "meal[]", default: []},
        device: "device?",
        ph11: "int?",
        ph71: "int?",
        ph12: "int?",
        ph72: "int?",
        cardinal_symptoms: {type: "cardinal_symptom[]", default: []},
    }
};

export default Test;
```

### DeviceData Schema

```
class DeviceData{}

DeviceData.schema = {
    name: 'data',
    primaryKey: "timestamp", //check to see if this is a good idea
    properties: {
        ph1: 'int',
        ph2: 'int',
        x: 'int',
        y: 'int',
        z: 'int',
        timestamp: 'int',
        raw: 'string' //base64, incase something went wrong
    }
};

export default DeviceData;
```

Comment: Is your schema name really `data`? If that is the case it might be a reserved word and might be breaking the realm code since there is already a [`data`](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#supported-types) type in realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a reserved word for realm since it already has a [data type](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#supported-types) as `data`. If the schema name changed to something else problem will be solved.

> Realm supports the following basic types: bool, int, float, double,
>   string, data, and date.
>
> - `bool` properties map to JavaScript `boolean` values
> - `int`, `float`, and `double` properties map to JavaScript number values. Internally `int` and `double` are stored as 64 bits while
>     `float` is stored with 32 bits.
> - `string` properties map to `string`
> - `data` properties map to `ArrayBuffer`
> - `date` properties map to `Date`